# While debugging, can I view object causing exception in LINQ?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq, debugging, exception

Lets say I have this code:

```
IDictionary<int, int> itemPriceDict = loadItemPriceDictionary();
IList<IRow> dbItems = loadItemsFromDatabase();

IList<ItemDTO> itemDTOs = dbItems
    .Select(dbItem => new ItemDTO()
    {
        Id = dbItem.Id,
        Label = dbItem.Label,
        PriceTag = itemPriceDict[dbItem.Id] // Possible KeyNotFoundException
    })
    .ToList();
```

and I sometimes get an KeyNotFound exception when given price tag does not exist
for the given dbItem.

Now, when debugging in Visual Studio and an exception is thrown, you can see StackTrace, TargetSite which show you what line of code triggered it, but
**is it possible to find out what object (dbItem) caused the exception and display it's data in Debugger? For example in Watch window?**

I would like to:

1. Either know which key was not present in the dictionary
2. Or better yet know the key and also the dbItem processed in Select

**But without any need to add or modify any code.**

P.S.: I know I can rewrite the code as cycle, but I would like not to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it is perfectly fine to inspect such object.
Here is the demo code in action:

[image: Inspecting variable in LINQ while exception is thrown]

Moreover, in Visual Studio 2015 it is possible to issue Lambda expression directly in Watch window to query collections before running the line which throws exception.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You could write your `Select` as such :

```
.Select(dbItem => 
    {
        return new ItemDTO()
        {
            Id = dbItem.Id,
            Label = dbItem.Label,
            PriceTag = itemPriceDict[dbItem.Id] // Possible KeyNotFoundException
        })
    }
    .ToList();
```

That would allow you to place breakpoints inside the select evaluations.

Better yet, go in the Debug Menu, then select Exceptions (it is under the Windows submenu on my Visual Studio Edition).

Then set it up so that it breaks on either `KeyNotFoundException` or any exception of your choice.

The debugger will then automatically break when an exception occurs allowing you to inspect the state of the related objects

Answer (score 4):

*[disclaimer: I work at OzCode]*

Have you tried OzCode. Linq debugging support was added to the [EAP](http://landing.oz-code.com/EAP) and one of the features is that it can predict if a query will throw an exception and show the offending item.

[image]

This way you don't need to dissect your code or try and debug it in your head.

Answer (score 3):

for debugging purposes you could do this:

```
 IList<ItemDTO> itemDTOs = dbItems
            .Select(dbItem => {
                try
                {
                    var value = itemPriceDict[dbItem.Id];
                }
                catch (KeyNotFoundException)
                {//Breakpoint goes here
                }
                // Possible KeyNotFoundException
                new ItemDTO()
                {
                    Id = dbItem.Id,
                    Label = dbItem.Label,
                    PriceTag = itemPriceDict[dbItem.Id] // Possible KeyNotFoundException
                };
            })
            .ToList();
```

or to directly get the list, this:

```
var missingKeys = dbitems.Where(dbItem => !itemPriceDict.ContainsKey(dbItem.Id)).ToList();
```

Comment: This works nicely for debugging purposes. But you have to rewrite the code. I would like to inspect the object in Watch Window or somewhere without having to modify existing code.

Comment: Your options are very limited if you don't want to change your code...
As far as I can tell, if you wish your code to remain unaltered, your only option is to set a breakpoint inside the LAMBA expression (the new ItemDTO part) then stop and check each ID in the dictionary manually.

Programming is a dynamic profession, you have to change your code if you wish to get proper results.

Comment: Of course we have to change our code while debugging. I was just curious if I can query the object in watch window/immediate window which is faster than modifying code, rebuilding and stepping/running to broken line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Try add another statment:

```
IList<ItemDTO> itemDTOs = dbItems.Where(dbitem => dbitem.itemPriceDict[dbItem.Id] != null)
    .Select(dbItem => new ItemDTO()
    {
        Id = dbItem.Id,
        Label = dbItem.Label,
        PriceTag = itemPriceDict[dbItem.Id] // Possible KeyNotFoundException
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: This would not work. You would get KeyNotFoundException in Where clause because dictionary does not return null when key is not present.

Comment: ok try that way:Where(dbitem => dbitem.itemPriceDict[dbItem.Id].Any())

Comment: Unfortuantelly you would get KeyNotFound exception as well. It happens at dbitem.itemPriceDict[dbItem.Id], before the call to Any(). You mean this: Where(dbItem => itemPriceDict.ContainsKey(dbItem.Id))   But I do not want to modify any code. I would to see it in debugger view - Watch window for example.

Comment: If you using Visual Studio you can check if you have `Common Language Runtime Exceptions` enabled: [LINK](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/02/23/the-new-exception-settings-window-in-visual-studio-2015/). Maby it will help you to debug problem.

Comment: @MKasprzyk the method you were searching for was [`.ContainsKey()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

When there is no key in the dictionary you will get a KeyNotFoundException exception. Keep a top variable and assign the key each time you put inside the Linq query.  You can decorate your code with try and catch block.

(KeyNotFoundException ex)

```
    try
    {
        int key;

        Dictionary<int, int> dict = new Dictionary<int, int>()
        {
            {1, 2},
            {2,3}
        };

        var x = (from y in dict
                 select new
                 {
                     value = dict[4]

                 }).ToList();

    }
    catch (KeyNotFoundException ex)
    {
         //key that is not there
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
```